# Why won't my dryer tumble?

Tags: dryer

I have a GE dryer (MODEL #DSXH43EF0WW) and it stopped working this morning.  The light still comes on when I open the door and the dryer will make a humming sound when I press the start button, but it will not actually begin to tumble.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to what the problem might be.

Searching online, I found that it is likely the thermal fuse that is at fault, but I wanted to know if there is something simpler that may be wrong (or if there is anything else that could be at fault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: So I got the dryer to work, but the solution was not what I expected. On a different forum, someone suggested that I open the dryer door and while holding down the door switch and the start button, spin the drum by hand. This actually got the dryer started. Subsequent starts work as normal (ie. no manual drum spinning required). The guy said that the problem was either that the drum hung up or that the motor is starting to go bad. I'm hoping it's the former.

Comment: I suggest that you open the dryer up to make sure that the belt is on there correctly.  I have had at least 3 family members in the past 2 years that had their dryer stop rolling because the belt has come off track somewhere.  The problem with you manually spinning it to get it going is if it is a bit off you by you spinning you helped it grab, the motor or the belt itself could be more susceptible to damage.  Mine actually came off right by the motor last year.

Comment: @ DMoore Thanks for this tip!  I will make sure to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that could be wrong would be that the drive belt had snapped. They do wear out. Replacements exist. How hard they are to install varies from model to model; mine wasn't bad, but did require disassembling the drier to the point where I could lift out the drum, and then required some access from the back to get the belt hooked around the drive pulleys properly. (I'm sure a pro could have done it entirely from the front, but this is the approach the maintenance manual I found online recommended.).

I'd suggest looking for the repair manual *first*. That'll generally have some problem analysis tips, and you'll want to see where the part is located and how to replace it before you decide to do it yourself.

Reminder: Disconnect from the wall before servicing!

Comment: So I got the dryer to work, but the solution was not what I expected. On a different forum, someone suggested that I open the dryer door and while holding down the door switch and the start button, spin the drum by hand. This actually got the dryer started. Subsequent starts work as normal (ie. no manual drum spinning required). The guy said that the problem was either that the drum hung up or that the motor is starting to go bad. I'm hoping it's the former.